# Running python function asynchronously without blocking caller function (and without needing the result)

Tags: python, django

I need to do a lengthy preprocessing step on POST requests to a given route (I'm using Django).
This will read a dataset, change some thing, and re-write it to disk (it can take a couple minutes).
I don't need the result of this function, I just want to execute it asynchronously and send an HTTP response immediately without waiting for it to end.

Currently like this it says the subroutine "preprocess_dataset_async" is never awaited on and it doesn't execute it fully.

```py
@require_POST
def preprocess_dataset(request, f_path=''):
    # ...
    preprocess_dataset_async(f_path, data)
    return HttpResponse('Request is being handled in the background', status=200)

async def preprocess_dataset_async(f_path, preprocess_args):
    # ...
    await stuff
    # ...
```

What would be the best way to execute this task in the background without blocking the caller function ?

Answer (score 0):

[`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) can be a possible solution for this.

But a better and far-sighted solution would be introducing [`Celery`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at Celery, I've also taken a look at [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)